# how to replicate bytes32 to uint256 conversion in javascript

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am attempting to replicate a bytes32 to uint256 conversion in nodejs. I would like to get the same result as this example contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract TestContract {


    bytes32 internal lastHash;

    constructor() {
        lastHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, now));
    }

    function getHash() public view returns(bytes32) {
        return lastHash;
    }

    function getHashNum() public view returns(uint256) {
        return uint256(lastHash);
    }
}
```

In a truffle test I've tried the following(along with many others):

```
const TestContract = artifacts.require('TestContract.sol');
const BigNumber = web3.BigNumber;


require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .use(require('chai-bignumber')(BigNumber))
  .should();


contract("TestContract", function(accounts) {

    it('can convert bytes32 to BigNumber in node', async function() {
        let contract = await TestContract.new({from:accounts[0]});
        let hash = await contract.getHash();
        let hashNum = await contract.getHashNum();
        let result = new BigNumber(hash);
        result.should.be.equal(hashNum);
    });

})
```

Basically I am not sure how the type conversion happens or how to replicate it in node. Any suggestions would be awesome!

**Edit**

The code above does work except for the last line. I needed to use the big number methods for compairing e.g.

```
assert(result.eq(hashNum) == true, "Result should be equal to hashNum");
```

Comment: You should add your last edit as answer so you can later mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ismael suggested here is the solution(in the edited op):

The code above does in fact work except for the last line

```
result.should.be.equal(hashNum);
```

I haven't bothered to check into why exactly that isn't working but I did find a working solution. I simply used the big number tools and assert:

```
assert(result.eq(hashNum) == true, "Result should be equal to hashNum");
```